# What was actually edible in the Room of Pure Imagination?

Tags: props, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

In *Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory*, when the characters enter the room of Pure Imagination (also known as the Chocolate Room) [where Willy Wonka sings his famous song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2pt2-F2j2g), what is actually edible in that room?

I would highly doubt that everything was, but there were objects in the room that characters were eating - even Willy Wonka took a bite of of a tea cup that was made out of what looked like a flower.

What props were actually edible in this scene of the movie?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie in a while, but I'd assume only the ones they are shown eating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking for the props then the answer is: Just the things they eat.

They probably didn't prepared extra one without telling cast and director what is edible. Plus actors trying things that are not prepared for consumption would result in opposite in "delight".